# How to tell entity framework code first to order the lazy loaded list

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Suppose I have the Following class

```
public class Account 
{
    public int AccountID {get; set;}
    public string AccountName {get; set;}
    public Account Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Account> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and I loaded list of accounts in a specific orderBy clause. my question is how can I tell entity framework code first to order the Children in a specific order when he lazy load that List?